# calculate the time difference using mssql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

i have to attribute from-time and to-time that is data type time

```
    create table timescale ( from_time time,to_time time)
```

first values is: 12:00 AM

second values is: 05:00 PM

i want to calculate time that how many hours i spend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`DATEDIFF`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function:

```
select DATEDIFF(hour, from_time, to_time)
from timescale
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert  timescale (from_time, to_time)
        Values('12:00 AM', '05:00 PM')


Select  (DATEDIFF(Hour ,From_time,to_time))
        From    timescale
```